# Copy the current "view" of a Photoshop Document w/o having to Flatten?

Tags: photoshop

Is there a way in Adobe Photoshop (I'm using CS4) to copy the current view of a document, including many different layers, to another application, such as InDesign, without having to flatten the image?

Comment: What is the difference between what you're looking for and "File" > "Save as"?

Comment: I dont' actually want to save the document in a different format, I just want to get the document, in its current state, into the clipboard so that I can place it into an Illustrator or InDesign file.

What I usually end up doing is flattening the image, selecting all, copying, and then going to InDesign and paste.

The reason I have to flatten the image is because if I don't, it only copies the active layer instead of the whole doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, pasting external graphical content into an InDesign file is not a great idea.

Much better is to "place" (CTRL+D) an external graphic file (Just a saved PSD would do fine) into InDesign. That way, any time the PSD file is updated in the future, InDesign will realise this and notify you via the "links" pallete (SHIFT+CTRL+D). My version will not automatically update the view, but if you are on CS4 Adobe should have that by now! (I am still on CS!).

Using the above, once you have "placed" your PSD the first time, you can change it as often as you like in Photoshop and its trivial to update the InDesign document.

Comment: berty this is extremely valuable information and I apologize for the delay in responding to it (I was on holiday) ... I'm curious how you would approach a situation where you had 1 photoshop document to illustrate multiple web pages and were using folders to show and hide, say for instance, the home page and interior page?

Comment: To my knowledge, to do that with InDesign you would need to save different versions of your Photoshop file, and insert each one into the document. Otherwise, Photoshop "Layer Comps" should be what you want. Showing different combinations of Layer Comps in InDesign in the same photoshop file would be a great feature, its certainly not in my version of the creative suite, it may have arrived in newer versions though.

Comment: berty ... thanks ... I had heard about Layer Comps in the past but never followed through, I will now.  This has been extremely useful ... I appreciate it